# How to run Unix command from Oracle Forms

Tags: unix, oas

OS: UNIX Solaries, Oracle Application Server 10g

To run shell script from Oracle Forms, I used the following `host('/bin/bash /u01/compile.sh')` and it works well

Now, I need to run unix command something like

`host('mv form1.fmx FORM1.FMX')` but it's not working

I tried to append the command  `mv form1.fmx FORM1.FMX'` to the compile.sh shell script but also it's not working although the rest lines of the shell script is running well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to just add the full path of the mv command and it worked well, as follow

`/bin/mv /u01/oracle/runtime/test/form1.fmx /u01/oracle/runtime/test/FORM1.FMX`

Answer (score -1):

In case anyone else encounters the same problem, the cause is that Forms process creates a subprocess to execute `host()` command, and that subprocess inherits environment variables of the parent process, which are derived from `default.env` (or other env file as defined in server config). There is a `PATH` variable defined in that file, but it doesn't contain usual `/bin` or `/usr/bin`, so the commands will not execute unless full path is specified.

The solution is to set the correct PATH variable either in the executed script (via `export PATH=$PATH:...`) or in `default.env`. I set it in the script, since, knowing Oracle, there's no guarantee that modifying `default.env` won't break something.